# Is it possible to determine the $\epsilon-steadiness$ of any arbitrary sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

**Definition** Let $\epsilon > 0$ be a rational number, and let $x,y$ be rational numbers. We say that $y$ is $\epsilon-close$ to $x$ iff we have $|x-y| \leq \epsilon$.

**Definition** Let $\epsilon > 0$. A sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^\inf$ of rational numbers is said to be $\epsilon-steady$ iff each pair $a_j, a_k$ of sequence elements is $\epsilon-close$ for every natural number $j,k$.

It's easy to see that the sequence $1,0,0,0,...$ is $1-steady$ because I **know** the underlying pattern of the sequence or the *rule* ( by rule/formula I mean something like $a_n = n^2$) by which the the sequence function ($f:N -> Q$) is determined i.e., every subsequent term in the sequence after the first term is $0$.

**My question**

1. How can we determine the $\epsilon-steadiness$ of an *arbitrary* sequence (i.e., the rule/formula defining the sequence function **may not be known**) of rational numbers using the above definition? Is the *formula* /*rule* necessary for the sequence function ($f:N -> Q$), so that we can apply the definition of $\epsilon-steadiness$?

Comment: $\sup a_n -\inf a_n$. You could have the definition without having a rule for the sequence, thought without a rule/formula it might be impossible to *apply* the definition

Comment: Actually the book that I am using have not reached the point where it has defined $supremum$ and $infimum$ yet . Is it possible to do without these concepts as well?